# C# ObservableCollection dosen't appear in TreeView by MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, mvvm, treeview

So I have a collection with `Name`, `Code`, `Id` and `List` with node type `ServiceTypeDto` like this model:

```
public class ServiceTypeDto
{
   public long Id
   public string Code
   public string Name
   public List<ServiceTypeDto> ChildrenList
}
```

I have a method which returns a list of `ServiceTypeDto`s, like this:

[image: List of Dto]

I have a `ChildernList` that exposes the `ServiceTypeDto`s.

This is how I try to do this in the **ViewModel**:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

using ServiceTypeService.Dto;
using ServiceTypeService.Interface;

using ShowServiceType.Interfaces;
using ShowServiceType.Utils;

namespace ShowServiceType.ViewModel
{
   class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
   {
      public string _name, _code;
      public long _id;
      public List<ServiceTypeDto> _childrenList = new List<ServiceTypeDto>();

      /// <summary>
      /// Create Services for work
      /// </summary>
      ILogService Log => Service.CreateLog();
      IExceptionHandler ExceptionHandler => Service.CreateExeptionHandler();
      IServiceType ServiceType => Service.CreateGetServiceType();


      public ObservableCollection<ServiceTypeDto> _servicesCollection;

      public MainWindowViewModel()
      {
         ServiceConfig.Initialization();
         var _services = ServiceType.GetServiceTypesTree();
         _servicesCollection = new ObservableCollection<ServiceTypeDto>();

         //This is convert to ObservableCollection my List<> =)
         foreach (var item in _services)
            _servicesCollection.Add(item);
      }

      public long ID
      {
         get => _id;
         set
         {
            _id = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ID");
         }
      }
      public string Code
      {
         get => _code;
         set
         {
            _code = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Code");
         }
      }
      public string Name
      {
         get => _name;
         set
         {
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
         }
      }
      public List<ServiceTypeDto> Children
      {
         get => _childrenList;
         set
         {
            _childrenList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Children");
         }
      }
   }
}
```

My `ViewModelBase` type:

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    
   public void OnPropertyChanged( string propname ) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this , new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propname));
}
```

Code-behind of my main window:

```
public MainWindow()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   ServiceConfig.Initialization();
   DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
}
```

Finally this is the XAML of the view.

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1">
   <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
      <TreeView>
         <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}">
               <StackPanel FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Orientation="Horizontal">
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding ID}" />
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Code}" />
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
               </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
         </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
      </TreeView>
   </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

The `ObservableCollection` dosen't appear in the `TreeView`. What is wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple issues in your view and view model:

- The `TreeView` is not bound to anything, bind its `ItemSource` to `Children`, otherwise it will not show any items
- The `ItemsSource` of the `HierarchicalDataTemplate` must be bound to the child collection within your `ServiceTypeDto`, which is `ChildrenList`, not `Children`
- You do not populate the `Children` collection (or its backing collection `_childrenList` ), so it is empty.
- You add items to `_servicesCollection`, but it is not used either
- The `ServiceTypeDto` does not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, so changes of properties will not be reflected in the user interface
- `ChildrenList` in the `ServiceTypeDto` is not an `ObservableCollection`, so adding or removing items will also not be reflected in the user interface

You should consider using a naming convention like `Children` for your property and `_children` for the backing field to improve readability of your code, look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-guidelines) for reference on naming in C#.

Comment: Just to add the backing field of `Children` should be renamed, so instead of `_childrenList` it should be `_children`. (thought you made a typo and had to double check if OP actually did this)

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Ok I bound on **View** my `TreeView.ItemSource` to `ChildrenList`

**2)** I don't understand how I bound `ChildList` in collection `ServiceTypeDto` to my `ObserveCollection`, How I understand wich index I select on UI ?

```
    public List<ServiceTypeDto> ChildrenList
        {
            get => _servicesCollection[0].ChildrenList; // ? index ?
            set
            {
                _servicesCollection[0].ChildrenList = value; // ? 0 ?
                OnPropertyChanged("ChildrenList");
            }
        }
    public string Name
        {
            get => _servicesCollection[0].Name; // ? 0 ?
            set
            {
                _servicesCollection[0].Name = value; // ? 
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
```

And other properties must know index to request from `_servicesCollection[index].Name` correct data?

**3)** I cant change `ChildrenList` in `ServiceTypeDto` to `ObserveCollection` out off dll, by condition of task.
This is just Reference.

[image: reference]

After this, I dont know how but its work with 0 index !
But work only first Nodes don't appear other list in subList

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
                <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ChildrenList}">
                    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ChildrenList}">
                            <StackPanel FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ID}" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Code}" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                </TreeView>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Grid>
```